# Problem with extending my div to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

I need help in extending my div to the bottom of the page when there is not enough content to do so, when I add a height of 100% to the content and container nothing changes and when I add it to the body everything messes up. I am trying to give as much information as possible and so have provided the CSS and HTML below.

### CSS:

(all of it, a lot of it is probably unnecessary in regards to this problem sorry)

```
body {
background-color: #111014;
background-image: url("images/bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #dad8df;
font-family: tahoma;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#container {
height: 100%;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

img{
border-style: none;
}

#banner {
margin-top: 45px;
margin-bottom: 38px;
height: 68px;
width: 1000px;
background-image: url("images/bannerbg.png");
}

#navigation {
height: 36px;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: 49px;
}

#content {
background-image: url("images/contentbg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
height: 100%;
width: 850px;
padding-left:80px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin-bottom: -8px;
padding-right: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#title {
height: 90px;
width: 542px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-top: 36px;
background-image: url("images/titlebg.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 2.5em;
color: #dad8df;
margin-left: -80px;
}

#slideshow {
height: 285px;
width: 840px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #2e2c35;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#slideleft {
height: 38px;
width: 23px;
background-image: url("images/slideleft.png");
float: left;
margin-left: -60px;
margin-top: 104px;
}

#slideright {
height: 38px;
width: 23px;
background-image: url("images/slideright.png");
float: right;
margin-right: -50px;
margin-top: 104px;
}

#emailform {
color: #dad8df;
font-family: tahoma;
overflow: hidden;
}

.inputs {
float: right;
width: 200px;
font: .9em tahoma;
}

#largemessage {
float: right;
clear: both;
width: 700px;
height: 150px;
resize: none;
font: .9em tahoma;
}

#submit {
margin-top: 20px;
clear: both;
float: right;
}

hr {
border-width: 3px 0 0 0;
border-style: dotted;
}

.contacterror {
margin-right: 180px;
height: 20px;
width: 300px;
color: red;
float: right;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<title>About :: Lesley Robb Fine Art and Design</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="banner">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/nav_home.png" alt="Home" /></a><a href="portfolio.php"><img src="images/nav_portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio" /></a><a href="about.php"><img src="images/nav_about.png" alt="About" /></a><a href="contact.php"><img src="images/nav_contact.png" alt="Contact" /></a>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="title">
About
</div>
You can edit this section after you Log In to the Control Panel. :)</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[The Page As it Currently Is](http://lesleyrobb.com/about.php)

[An image of it for future reference once I have fixed the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq91s.png)

Thanks in advance for your time,
Callum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a technique called [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Comment: I fixed it, although It took me a while and I didn't directly use this method but it helped me along the way, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you add

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}
```

the `container div` will inherit from it.

Comment: As you can see if you visit the page again, it messes up completely, I will have a look later this afternoon though because I think I should either have no container or make the container height and width 100% and set the background image for that. I think the first one should work better though. I'll try figure it out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height on your #container div to auto.

```
#container { 
     height:auto;
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

As the doc said:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

If adding `html,body { height:100%; }` mess up, it's certainly because browsers set default margin/padding for these elements.

The simpler solution for your problem is to set for `#container` min-height the viewport height and set it a background which will fake `#content` reaches the bottom. [Faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) as Nathaniel said.